# Nginx Serves files but denies folder access

Tags: nginx

I've tried a couple of different things to stop access to the files but none seem to work.

Currently using ISP config on debian jessie. I'm hosting a webmail (rainloop) client from there for personal use.

I'm also adding my changes to the nginx directives section of ISPConfig.

The problem I am experiencing is that I get a forbidden error when attempting to access the /data folder and any sub directory (this works as intended) but I found that I was able to access all files within pretty much any directory...oops...

Default directory for the data folder at the bottom of the vhost is:
/var/www/clients/client1/MYSERVER.COM/web/webmail/data

Vhost:

```
server {
        listen SERVER_IP_HERE:80;

        listen SERVER_IP_HERE:443 ssl;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/clients/client1/web5/ssl/MYSERVER.COM-le.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/clients/client1/web5/ssl/MYSERVER.COM-le.key;

        server_name MYSERVER.COM ;

        root   /var/www/MYSERVER.COM/web/;

        if ($scheme != "https") {
            rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
        }


        index index.html index.htm index.php index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml;



        error_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/MYSERVER.COM/error.log;
        access_log /var/log/ispconfig/httpd/MYSERVER.COM/access.log combined;

        location ~ /\. {
            deny all;
        }

        location ^~ /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
            access_log off;
            log_not_found off;
            root /usr/local/ispconfig/interface/acme/;
            autoindex off;
            index index.html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

        location = /favicon.ico {
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
            expires max;
            add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
        }

        location = /robots.txt {
            allow all;
            log_not_found off;
            access_log off;
        }

        location /stats/ {

            index index.html index.php;
            auth_basic "Members Only";
            auth_basic_user_file /var/www/clients/client1/web5/web/stats/.htpasswd_stats;
        }

        location ^~ /awstats-icon {
            alias /usr/share/awstats/icon;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files /12c2654cada4d332b002b97dbfb4002d.htm @php;
        }

        location @php {
            try_files $uri =404;
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/lib/php5-fpm/web5.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        }




        location ^~ /data {
          deny all;
        }



}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What about just, `location /data { deny all; }`

Comment: Please clarify what exactly is your objective here? It is unclear from your text.

Comment: The evidence suggests that this is not the `server` block currently handling requests for `/test`. Test your configuration using `nginx -T`